# Chart.js and long labels

Tags: charts, chart.js, radar-chart

I use Chart.js to display a Radar Chart. My problem is that some labels are very long :
the chart can't be display or it appears very small.

So, is there a way to break lines or to assign a max-width to the labels?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please provide your code .

Answer (score 64):

For Chart.js 2.0+ you can use an array as label:

Quoting the DOCs:

> "Usage: If a label is an array as opposed to a string i.e. [["June","2015"], "July"] then each element is treated as a seperate line."

```
var data = {
   labels: [["My", "long", "long", "long", "label"], "another label",...],
   ...
}
```

Comment: I coudn't find any explicit mention to this in documentation itself but there's a [Multiline labels](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/multiline-labels.html) example in website [samples](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/).

Comment: It also does not seem to work on radar charts as the OP requested: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/2704#issuecomment-229646686

Comment: spent 2 whole days trying to solve an issue and this answer solved it, you are the one. :)

Comment: this only works for the x-axis. any tips for the y axis?

Comment: This feels like a workaround, but it works so its fine

Answer (score 32):

With ChartJS 2.1.6 and using @ArivanBastos [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37899399/3467079)

Just pass your long label to the following function, it will return your label in an array form, each element respecting your assigned maxWidth.

```js
/** 
 * Takes a string phrase and breaks it into separate phrases 
 * no bigger than 'maxwidth', breaks are made at complete words.
 */
function formatLabel(str, maxwidth){
  var sections = [];
  var words = str.split(" ");
  var temp = "";

  words.forEach(function(item, index){
    if(temp.length > 0)
    {
      var concat = temp + ' ' + item;

      if(concat.length > maxwidth){
        sections.push(temp);
        temp = "";
      }
      else{
        if(index == (words.length-1)) {
          sections.push(concat);
          return;
        }
        else {
          temp = concat;
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    if(index == (words.length-1)) {
      sections.push(item);
      return;
    }

    if(item.length < maxwidth) {
      temp = item;
    }
    else {
      sections.push(item);
    }

  });

  return sections;
}

console.log(formatLabel("This string is a bit on the longer side, and contains the long word Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious for good measure.", 10))
```

Comment: Really nice! Thank you Fermin +1

Comment: excellent, add it to the project, core or [plugin](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html)

Comment: btw, it should also be clear that `maxwidth`refers to characters and not pixels or any other measurements

Comment: @fermin this works fine except it also adds  a line break to the tooltip... not so ideal.

Answer (score 11):

To wrap the xAxes label, put the following code into optoins. (this will split from white space and wrap into multiple lines)

```
scales: {         
  xAxes: [
    {
      ticks: {
        callback: function(label) {
          if (/\s/.test(label)) {
            return label.split(" ");
          }else{
            return label;
          }              
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It works, use this regex expression based wrapping than breaking label. Great.

Comment: Awesome and works when dynamically changing charts and re-rendering them, thank you.

Comment: The height doesn't auto-adjust when this technique is used for the y-axis. the text is written over each other

Comment: for me instead of the string label it returns numbers 0 to 4 (having 5 labels)

Comment: @Kaspatoo You need to use this.getLabelForValue(value).

As documented below : The category axis, which is the default x-axis for line and bar charts, uses the index as internal data format. For accessing the label, use this.getLabelForValue(value). API: getLabelForValue

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.8.2/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats

Answer (score 2):

You can write a javascript function to customize the label:

`// Interpolated JS string - can access value
    scaleLabel: "<%=value%>",`

See http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no solution for this until now (April 5th 2016).
There are multiple issues on Chart.js to deal with this:

- https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/358 (closed with fix)
- https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/608 (closed with no fix)
- https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/358 (closed with no fix)
- https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/780 (closed with no fix)
- https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/752 (closed with no fix)

This is a workaround: [Remove x-axis label/text in chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424123/remove-labels-in-chart-js/26755020#26755020)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you might be actually be talking about data labels and not the scale labels. In this case you'd want to use the `pointLabelFontSize` option. See below example:

```
var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");

var data = {
  labels: ["Eating", "Sleeping", "Coding"],
  datasets: [
    {
        label: "First",
        strokeColor: "#f00",
        pointColor: "#f00",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "#ccc",
        data: [45, 59, 90]
    },
    {
        label: "Second",
        strokeColor: "#00f",
        pointColor: "#00f",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "#ccc",
        data: [68, 48, 40]
    }
  ]
};

// This is the important part
var options = {
  pointLabelFontSize : 20
};

var myRadarChart = new Chart(ctx).Radar(data, options);
```

Finally you may want to play with the dimensions of your < canvas > element as I've found sometimes giving the Radar chart more height helps the auto scaling of everything.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way to manipulate the labels on the radar chart was by using the [pointlabels configuration from Chartjs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html#point-label-options).

```
let skillChartOptions = {
    scale: {
      pointLabels: {
        callback: (label: any) => {
          return label.length > 5 ? label.substr(0, 5) + '...' : label;
        },
      }, ...
    }, ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to further extend on Fermin's answer with a slightly more readable version. As previously pointed out, it's possible to give Chart.js an array of strings to make it wrap the text. To make this array of strings from a longer string, I propose this function:

```js
function chunkString(str, maxWidth){
  const sections = [];
  const words = str.split(" ");
  let builder = "";

  for (const word of words) {
    if(word.length > maxWidth) {
      sections.push(builder.trim())
      builder = ""
      sections.push(word.trim())
      continue
    }

    let temp = `${builder} ${word}`
    if(temp.length > maxWidth) {
      sections.push(builder.trim())
      builder = word
      continue
    }

    builder = temp
  }
  sections.push(builder.trim())

  return sections;
}

const str = "This string is a bit on the longer side, and contains the long word Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious for good measure."
console.log(str)
console.log(chunkString(str, 10))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100vh!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For most of the recent versions of chart.js, the labels can be mentioned as array of arrays. That's your labels can be:

```
labels = [['a', 'label1'],['the', 'lable2'],label3] '$'
```

You can use following function which is fast and compatible across all versions for converting your labels array into array of array in case the labels contain multiple words:

```
function splitLongLabels(labels){
    //labels = ["ABC PQR", "XYZ"];  
    var i = 0, len = labels.length;
    var splitlabels = labels;
    while (i < len) {
        var words = labels[i].trim().split(' ');
        if(words.length>1){
      for(var j=0; j<words.length; j++){
      }
      splitlabels[i] = words;
        }   
        i++
        }
    
    return splitlabels;
}
```