# Remove x-axis label/text in chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

How do I hide the x-axis label/text that is displayed in chart.js ?

Setting `scaleShowLabels:false` only removes the y-axis labels.

```
<script>
    var options = {
        scaleFontColor: "#fa0",
        datasetStrokeWidth: 1,
        scaleShowLabels : false,
        animation : false,
        bezierCurve : true,
        scaleStartValue: 0,
    };
    var lineChartData = {
        labels : ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"],
        datasets : [
            {
                fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                data : [1,3,0,0,6,2,10]
            }
        ]

    }

var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData,options);

</script>
```

Answer (score 176):

## UPDATE chart.js 2.1 and above

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    ...
    options:{
        scales:{
            xAxes: [{
                display: false //this will remove all the x-axis grid lines
            }]
        }
    }
});


var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    ...
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    display: false //this will remove only the label
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

[Reference: chart.js documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-chart-options)

**Old answer (written when the current version was 1.0 beta) just for reference below:**

To avoid displaying labels in `chart.js` you have to set `scaleShowLabels : false` and also avoid to pass the `labels`:

```
<script>
    var options = {
        ...
        scaleShowLabels : false
    };
    var lineChartData = {
        //COMMENT THIS LINE TO AVOID DISPLAYING THE LABELS
        //labels : ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"],
        ... 
    }
    ...
</script>
```

Comment: please downvoter tell me how to improve my answer,  thanks

Comment: Does not work. Commenting the labels out makes the chart throw an error on update.

Comment: @OhCaN this answer was written when the current version of chartjs was v1.0 beta i have running implementations with that code and they all work fine.

Comment: Newer highchart version? This question is about chart.js. Not highcharts.

Comment: If I'm right, this solution also removes the "background grid" ( I don't know the proper reference, the gray bars behind the graph ). Is there a solution that only removes the "labels" as OP requested?

Comment: Nothing of the above mentioned works for my bar chart, chart.js 2.4.0.
--> and also avoid to pass the labels.
This should really be only a switch, so passing labels shouldn't be a concern here. Waiting for chart.js 3.x :)

Comment: I am using ng2-charts 1.5.0 and this code works fine.

Comment: @giammin, your script is not working in my case, can we discuss.

Comment: @user123 this is a really old answer and i have not used highcharts since them... i dont think i can help you, sorry

Comment: As @StevenPalinkas noted this will remove all the x-axis grid lines as well as the label text. Not ideal.

Comment: @MattK you are right. I updated my answer accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 46):

## This is for chart.js ^3.0.0

#### Remove x-axis labels and grid chart lines

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    ...
    options:{
        scales:{
            x: {
                display: false
            }
        }
    }
});
```

#### Remove only x-axis labels

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    ...
    options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
               ticks: {
                   display: false
              }
           }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: So it's like @giammin answer, but for the newer versions?

Comment: Yes, I use chart.js 3.0.2 and that works for me

Answer (score 18):

(this question is a duplicate of [In chart.js, Is it possible to hide x-axis label/text of bar chart if accessing from mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673804/))
They added the option, 2.1.4 (and maybe a little earlier) has it

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    display: false
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```js
var lineChartData = {
    labels: ["", "", "", "", "", "", ""] // To hide horizontal labels
 ,datasets : [
  {
   label: "My First dataset",
   fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
   strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
   pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
   pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
   pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
   pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
   
   data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
  }
 ]
}



window.onload = function(){
 var options = {
  scaleShowLabels : false // to hide vertical lables
 };
 var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");
 window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, options);

}
```

Answer (score 8):

Faced this issue of removing the labels in Chartjs now. Looks like the documentation is improved.
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration

```
Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
```

this global settings prevents legends from being shown in all Charts. Since this was enough for me, I used it. I am not sure to how to avoid legends for individual charts.

Comment: Using Version: 2.1.6, this one did the trick. Also, without using global you could: `options:{
        legend: {
             display: false,
         },`

Comment: perfect ! that's what I am looking for. But it has to be set before the chart is rendered. Doesn't work afterwards...

Answer (score 8):

For those whom this did not work, here is how I hid the labels on the X-axis-

```
options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 1,
        right: 2,
        top: 2,
        bottom: 0,
      },
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          time: {
            unit: 'Areas',
          },
          gridLines: {
            display: false,
            drawBorder: false,
          },
          ticks: {
            maxTicksLimit: 7,
            display: false, //this removed the labels on the x-axis
          },
          'dataset.maxBarThickness': 5,
        },
      ],
```

Answer (score 6):

Inspired by christutty's answer, here is a solution that modifies the source but has not been tested thoroughly. I haven't had any issues yet though.

In the defaults section, add this line around line 71:

```
// Boolean - Omit x-axis labels
omitXLabels: true,
```

Then around line 2215, add this in the buildScale method:

```
//if omitting x labels, replace labels with empty strings           
if(Chart.defaults.global.omitXLabels){
    var newLabels=[];
    for(var i=0;i<labels.length;i++){
        newLabels.push('');
    }
    labels=newLabels;
}
```

This preserves the tool tips also.

Comment: I solved it inserting those lines BEFORE :this.buildScale(data.labels); Line:  2375.    var newLabels=[];
   for(var i=0;i<data.labels.length;i++){
    newLabels.push('');
   }         Then change also with:  this.buildScale(newLabels);

Answer (score 3):

If you want the labels to be retained for the tooltip, but not displayed below the bars the following hack might be useful.  I made this change for use on an private intranet application and have not tested it for efficiency or side-effects, but it did what I needed.

At about line 71 in chart.js add a property to hide the bar labels:

```
// Boolean - Whether to show x-axis labels
barShowLabels: true,
```

At about line 1500 use that property to suppress changing this.endPoint (it seems that other portions of the calculation code are needed as chunks of the chart disappeared or were rendered incorrectly if I disabled anything more than this line).

```
if (this.xLabelRotation > 0) {
    if (this.ctx.barShowLabels) {
        this.endPoint -= Math.sin(toRadians(this.xLabelRotation)) * originalLabelWidth + 3;
    } else {
        // don't change this.endPoint
    }
}
```

At about line 1644 use the property to suppress the label rendering:

```
if (ctx.barShowLabels) {    
    ctx.fillText(label, 0, 0);
}
```

I'd like to make this change to the Chart.js source but aren't that familiar with git and don't have the time to test rigorously so would rather avoid breaking anything.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is:

`scaleFontSize: 0`

see the [chart.js Document](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration)

[smilar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673804)

Comment: This would remove the y axis scale also.

Comment: scaleFontSize is not a valid property

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: chartjs ^4.2.0 + react-chartjs-2 ^5.2.0

Axis was removed.

```
const options = {
legend: {
  display: false,
},
scales: {
  x: {
    display: false,
  },
  y: {
    display: false,
  },
},
```