# In chart.js, Is it possible to hide x-axis label/text of bar chart if accessing from mobile?

Tags: jquery, chart.js

In chart.js, Is it possible to hide **x-axis** label/text of bar chart if accessing from mobile ?

[image]

I Wanna hide/remove labels on **x-axis** ie "January", "February" etc...

Comment: i think you mean x-axis if you are on about the dataset labels on the bottom

Comment: yes i mean x-axis, is it possible, in chart.js or chartNew.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've added a new option.

http://www.knighttube.com/scripts/chart.js

http://www.knighttube.com/scripts/chart.min.js

showXAxisLabel:false

Comment: Add some details to support your answer. Link to external resources may expire in future.

Comment: with  chartnew.js,you can hide y-axis label and more, it's More advance than chart.js . and i edit a site (http://charts.livegap.com) that generate the chart code. with live preview for chartnew.js

Comment: This could be awesome. But I need more info.

Answer (score 8):

They added the option, 2.1.4 (and maybe a little earlier) has it

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    display: false
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Answer of @Kapytanhook is correct for `chart.js` version **2.x.x**

For those interested, following modification of his answer for ...

### chart.js v3.x.x

(as **v3.x.x** is not backward compatible with **v2.x.x**)

```js
const myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {  // <-- object '{' now, instead of array '[{' before in v2.x.x
        ticks: {
          display: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**Programmatically:**
Also, as questions mentiones to **show/hide** the lables/ticks, I added a button to modify the chart programmatically:

```js
myLineChart.options.scales['x'].ticks.display = true;
myLineChart.update();
```

Following complete code with sample data to run snippet and see result with hidden x-axis ticks.

```js
const labels = ["2021-08-02","2021-08-03","2021-08-04","2021-08-05","2021-08-06"];
const data_1 = [39,41,42,43,43];
const data_2 = [37,38,40,41,39];

const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');

const btnShowHide = document.querySelector('#btnShowHide');

const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Data 1',
    borderColor: 'grey',
    data: data_1
  }, {
    label: 'Data 2',
    borderColor: 'grey',
    data: data_2
  }]
};

const myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: { // <-- object '{' now, instead of array '[{' before in v2.x.x
        ticks: {
          display: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

btnShowHide.onclick = function() {
  if(btnShowHide.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    myLineChart.options.scales['x'].ticks.display = true;
    myLineChart.update();
    
    btnShowHide.classList.remove('hidden');
    btnShowHide.innerHTML = 'hide';
  } else {
    myLineChart.options.scales['x'].ticks.display = false;
    myLineChart.update();
    
    btnShowHide.classList.add('hidden')
    btnShowHide.innerHTML = 'show';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<!-- gets you the latest version of Chart.js, now at v3.5.0 -->

<button id="btnShowHide" class="hidden">show</button>

<div style="width:320px">
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to toggle the x -axis on a button click.Thanks! This answer helped me with a small change : myLineChart.options.scales['xAxes'][0].ticks.display = true;

Answer (score 2):

I got around this by defining labels as a list of empty strings. Example:

```
var data = {
    labels: ["", "", "", "", ""],
    datasets: [{
        label: "TEST",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [10, 20, 15, 8, 22]
    }]
};
```

For this you need the label to not be relevant in the tooltip box. I defined mine as follows:

```
tooltipTemplate: "Latency: <%=value%>"
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is:

`scaleFontSize: 0`

see the [chart.js Document](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration)

Comment: This will hide both x and y i believe

Comment: I tried this and it crashes the browser page in chrome

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the current BarChart and remove the xLabels like this.

```
function registerCustomBarChart() {
    Chart.types.Bar.extend({
        name: "customBarChart",
        initialize: function (data) {
            Chart.types.Bar.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
            var xLabels = this.scale.xLabels
            xLabels.forEach(function (label, i) {
                    xLabels[i] = '';
            })
        }
    });
}
```

`var myBarChart = new Chart(context).customBarChart(data);`

Answer (score 0):

Charts.js provides the responsive charts [configuration options](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html?h=respon#configuration-options) among 
 which there is the `onResize` method. It gets passed two arguments: the chart instance and the new size. Should you log both to the console you'll see the complete chart instance there that includes all the regular options to control the chart instance `scales`.

I added this to the `options` object on the `Bar` chart instance so the X axis disappears on resize to the width of 768 px then appears on the resize back to the desktop screen size. The `Bar` instance was the Chart.js React wrapper provided by the react-chartjs-2 library.

```
<Bar
  data={barData}
  options={{
    // default value
    responsive: true,
    onResize: function(newChart, newSize) {
      console.log('newChart:', newChart);
      console.log('newSize:', newSize);

      if (newSize.width < 768) {
        newChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].display = false;
      } else {
        newChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].display = true;
      }
    }, ...
```

For a `Pie` instance switch `newChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].display` for `newChart.options.legend.display`.