# How to hide the y axis and x axis line and label in my bar chart for chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I am new to Chart.js and I want to hide the y axis and x axis line and label in my chart. I looked at the documentation and couldn't find a good option. Has anyone else encountered this problem and have a solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the showScale option would be better

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("LineWithLine").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
    showScale: false
});
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/wb3kcunt/

This hides gridlines too. If you want to hide only the axes and labels and not the grid lines, just set scaleFontColor and scaleLineColor to a transparent color.

Comment: and how would you do that only for the x axis? I am googling the solution like 10 hours already

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you edit a library posted in this answer, you can achieve this

[In chart.js, Is it possible to hide x-axis label/text of bar chart if accessing from mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673804/in-chart-js-is-it-possible-to-hide-y-axis-label-text-of-bar-chart-if-accessing)