# How to remove x axis scale labels Chart.Js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, linegraph

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6UVO.png)

I created a chart using chart.js and it works as expected. The problem is that I don't need the x axis labels (Speed). I looked at questions similar to this but none of them worked. How do you hide the x axis labels without removing or changing anything else in chart.js v3?

Comment: This chart is unintentionally hilarious.  How fast was it going? Speed.

Comment: @Deadron I tried that but It dosen't seem to work

Comment: The question is duplicate of the following  - than the one it was closed for: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424123/remove-x-axis-label-text-in-chart-js

Comment: @Charlie i looked and tested the answers in the post but none worked.

Comment: Solutions given in both the answers are working. The accepted answer is running on this page itself and showing no X labels.

Comment: i tried the solutions before i posted this and they dont work for me @Charlie

Comment: This means you have other error than what you have posted here. You can see its working if you run @LeeLenalees' answer right withing the page

Comment: @Charlie most didn't produce an error

Comment: @LeeLenaLees' answer was not in the possible duplicate answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do 2 things, either supply an labels array with empty strings or use the tick callback to provide empty labels

```
 scales: {
            x: {
                ticks: {
                    // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return '';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    // option 1, provide empty strings for labels array
    labels: ["", "", "", "", "", ""],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          //option 2, use callback to change labels to empty string
          callback: () => ('')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.1.1/chart.js" integrity="sha512-aWx9jeVTj8X49UzUnUHGIlo6rNne1xNsCny/lL0QwUTQK2eilrHXpSk9xbRm4FJ4eLi2XBmnFlRkWPoChSx8bA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply disable the x axis labels by one flag like this:

```
 options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          display: false
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Wont work, chart.js needs labels to match the data to, so not providing that array and only an array of numbers for data doesnt show anything

Comment: @LeeLenalee You are correct. The answer editied.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work

Comment: For me this is the solution. Thnx (Using vue-chartjs).