# How to create a multiline chartjs axis title

Tags: chart.js

I see that an array can be used to create *multiline* labels in chartjs.
[Chart.js and long labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409717/chart-js-and-long-labels)

I want a multiline scaleLabel. Currently the array displays the result on one line. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: [[firstCategory + ': ' + avg1], [ secondCategory + ': ' + avg2]],
            fontSize: 20
        }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
    }]
}
```