# Javascript Canvas labels too long

Tags: javascript

When I use small version numbers (the label), my canvas is shown as it should:

[image: Good Canvas view]

But when my labels get too long it starts to look very unreadable, and I don't know how to avoid this?:

[image: Bad Canvas view]

Can I change my options to solve this, if yes, how?

Here is my javascript function, and `nameArray` is the array with version numbers, and I have to shorten these somehow.

```js
function renderBarChart(nameArray, passArray, failArray, divId, title) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById(divId).getContext('2d');

    var newChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: nameArray,
            datasets: [{
                    label: 'Passed',
                    data: passArray,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(150,238,144)'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Failed',
                    data: failArray,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(204,0,0)'
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: title
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'index',
                intersect: false,
            },
            hover: {
                mode: 'nearest',
                intersect: true
            },
            responsive: false,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    stacked: true,
                    ticks: {
                        stepSize: 1,
                        min: 0,
                        autoSkip: false
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    stacked: true,
                    ticks: {
                        maxTicksLimit: 5,
                        min: 0
                    }
                }]
            }

        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT 1**

Right now I'm trying to do something like this, but I can't make it work.
Inspiration form: [How to shorten Chart.js label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396737/how-to-shorten-chart-js-label)

```js
function renderBarChart(nameArray, passArray, failArray, divId, title) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById(divId).getContext('2d');

    var newChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: nameArray,
            datasets: [{
                    label: 'Passed',
                    data: passArray,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(150,238,144)'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Failed',
                    data: failArray,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(204,0,0)'
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: title
            },
            tooltips: {
                enabled: true,
                mode: 'label',
                callbacks: {
                    title: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                        var idx = tooltipItems[0].index;
                        return 'Title:' + data.labels[idx]; //do something with title
                    },
                    label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                        //var idx = tooltipItems.index;
                        //return data.labels[idx] + ' €';
                        return tooltipItems.xLabel + ' €';
                    }
                }
            },
            hover: {
                mode: 'nearest',
                intersect: true
            },
            responsive: false,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    stacked: true,
                    ticks: {
                        stepSize: 1,
                        min: 0,
                        autoSkip: false,
                        callback: function(value) {
                            if (value.length > 4) {
                                return value.substr(0, 4) + '...'; //truncate
                            } else {
                                return value
                            }

                        },
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    stacked: true,
                    ticks: {
                        maxTicksLimit: 5,
                        min: 0
                    }
                }]
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Not gonna lie `Bad Canvas view` looks pretty cool 

Comment: Hahaha! @ManasKhandelwal yes it looks pretty wild 

Comment: The solution might be there with the chart library which you have used. Which library have you used?

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri I'm using this: [chartjs](https://www.chartjs.org/)

Comment: Please check here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409717/chart-js-and-long-labels

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri Right now I'm trying to use this, but I can't make it work.. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396737/how-to-shorten-chart-js-label

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri Made a edit with the code I have right now, can you see what my issue is?

Comment: Is your truncate callback function getting called? Check by keeping logs in it.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri Yes it's called, but I can't seem to make this work :/